# Windows 8.1 erased Ubuntu 14.04 partition

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8, data-recovery, partitioning

I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed with a Windows 7 dual boot. Now, I've just replaced W7 by Windows 8, but the Ubuntu partition has disappeared!

Running `fdisk -l` doesn't show `/dev/sda5` (which was the Ubuntu partition), if I access to Gparted, it shows the Ubuntu partition as "empty space" and from Windows 8's device manager, this partition also appears as empty space!

WTF has happened here? Has the partition been actually erased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could recover all the data using `testdisk` utility from an Ubuntu live CD!

It seems that Windows damaged the hdd MBR and using this program I could inspect the real hdd contents and then re-write the MBR without problems and recovering the whole partition.

To install it just do a `sudo apt-get install testdisk`

Answer (score 0):

If GParted says the partition where Ubuntu once resided is empty then it is almost certainly erased. Very strange, I'm entirely unsure how that could have happened.

Comment: I've added an answer that expains how I recovered all the data :)

Comment: Nice! Thank you for sharing. I was unaware of that fix. :D